# BCC creates email via email-to-case but not visible in Salesforce

Tags: email2case

Our organization uses email-to-case with several different email addresses routing to different queues upon case creation. Sometimes, a case is created and assigned to a specific queue based on the 'bcc' on the inbound email. However, I cannot see that bcc. Is there a way to get access to this?

Thanks!

Comment: so the `bcc` corresponds to a configured E2C address (hence that is how the Case is created via E2C)?

Comment: Correct @cropredy. However, we have processes we trigger based on the 'to' and/or 'cc' line on the Email object being an E2C address, which we cannot easily trigger in this scenario.